# aggregation on keyword field fails

Tags: elasticsearch-5

I currently have the issue, that 3 out of 6 aggregations fail with the error.

```
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [experience_slug] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory."
```

The fields in question are defined as type keyword (with doc_values true), thus should pose no problem for querying. (taken straight from the _mapping section):

```
      "experience_slug": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        },
        "analyzer": "default",
        "search_analyzer": "default_search"
      },
```

Since neither the documentation, nor google, nor StackOverflow does provide answers for this problem, i assume there is something fundamentally wrong.

The only thing i could imagine, was unset data in the field. Now the field is assured to have content.
Also in the process, i have removed every other part of the query to isolate the problem, used `aggs`as well as `aggregations`, renamed the name of the aggregation just to be sure..

Here is the request body and anonymized search url:

```
http://localhost:9200/project_development/some_type/_search


{
  "aggregations": {
    "foo": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "experience_slug"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Elasticsearch 5.2.2 in the official docker container with limited (but sufficient) Memory.
No entries in the logs either.

I'd appreciate any hint on how to solve this dilemma.

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation requires a different data structure rather than inverted index.
For eg

If i index a field with these values and standard analyzer
data brown ,
    dog    ,
    dogs    ,
    fox    ,
    foxes   ,
    in      ,
    jumped  ,
    lazy    ,
    leap   ,
    over   ,
    quick ,  summer ,the

This is inverted index

```
Term      Doc_1   Doc_2   Doc_3
------------------------------------
brown   |   X   |   X   |
dog     |   X   |       |   X
dogs    |       |   X   |   X
fox     |   X   |       |   X
foxes   |       |   X   |
in      |       |   X   |
jumped  |   X   |       |   X
lazy    |   X   |   X   |
leap    |       |   X   |
over    |   X   |   X   |   X
quick   |   X   |   X   |   X
summer  |       |   X   |
the     |   X   |       |   X
```

Structure used by aggregation

```
Doc      Terms
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Doc_1 | brown, dog, fox, jumped, lazy, over, quick, the
Doc_2 | brown, dogs, foxes, in, lazy, leap, over, quick, summer
Doc_3 | dog, dogs, fox, jumped, over, quick, the
```

So for aggregation either

- doc_value should be enabled on field
- field_data should be enabled on field.

Now,

1. doc_values can only be enabled on not_analyzed string fields.
2. field_data is by defualt disabled on analyzed string fields from elasticsearch 5

Now **solution is**

- either aggregate on field **experience_slug.keyword**
- Or enable field_data on **experience_slug**.

But make sure this both will give different results as experience_slug will aggregate on terms generated after analyzing

experience_slug.keyword will aggregate on full value of field.

**experience_slug and experience_slug.keyword** are two different fields with different settings but same data.

Comment: As i said, doc_values are on. In one of my trials i did also activate fielddata, just to make sure. It was ignored tho (as the type is keyword..). Using `experience_slug.keyword` did work tho, for some unknown reason.

Comment: experience_slug.keyword is working because keyword type in es is not_analyzed and doc_values is enabled by default on not_analyzed string fields

Comment: experience_slug was not working as it was analyzed string field on whcih doc_values cannot be enabled and field_data is by default off on that

Comment: And aggregation aggregates on terms produced at index time.
So keyword fields would aggregate whole data and text fields with standard analyzer would aggregate on terms produced by standard analyzer.

Comment: As i understand it: When the actual data type is text ( not the field type ), i have to either set `"fielddata": true` or use the `.keyword`-notation to aggregate properly.